# AX2012 Using Select query to display data in a data grid view

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

i have new form and I am looking for to display all record  in grid byn specifying my own query ,the fonction may be as well:

```
static void  queryVendtableSelect(Args _args)
{
    VendTable vendTable;

    while select firstOnly  *
    from vendTable
    order by   vendTable.AccountNum
     where vendTable.Blocked =="aaaaaaaaa"


    }
```

when can i put this fontion?
any idea. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could overwrite the `init` or `executeQuery` method of the form datasource that references your table. In the overwritten method, you can create a new query and set it as the query of the datasource or you can modify the query of the datasource. See [How to filter records in a form by code](http://dynamics-ax-live.blogspot.de/2010/03/how-to-filter-records-in-form-by-code.html) for an example of modifying the datasource query.

Answer (score 5):

For the provided example you can override the `init` method in the VendTable datasource as follows:

```
public void init()
{
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
    QueryBuildRange qbr;

    super();

    qbds = this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(VendTable));
    qbds.sortClear();
    qbds.addSortField(fieldNum(VendTable, AccountNum));
    qbr = SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(qbds, fieldNum(VendTable, Blocked));
    qbr.value(queryValue('aaaaaaaaa')); 
}
```